# Name of the food in the picture in Japanese and i can't identify it in English, either

Tags: word-requests, food

[image]

What is this food? It looks like Taiyaki, however, I can't identify it.

Comment: アメリカンドッグ？　https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjox57Io-zPAhVGKpQKHaKyBn0Q_AUICCgB

Comment: What's inside of it..?

Comment: 見た目だと凄く甘そう　　（パンケーキ風）

Answer (score 7):

It resembles a food known as [ワッフルドッグ](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%83%AF%E3%83%83%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0&tbm=isch), [チーズワッフル](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%83%81%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%83%AF%E3%83%83%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB&tbm=isch), or [原宿ドッグ](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8E%9F%E5%AE%BF%E3%83%89%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0&tbm=isch).

As the name suggests, its ingredient is typically cheese.

---

[image]

Comment: I am very sorry Brocolli, those you picked don't have a stick. So I must go to David S's answer because he directly gives a **Japanese sample** whose shape is exactly same with that in the question.

Comment: And if inside were cheese, it it easier for us to eat? I mean with a stick?

Comment: @KentaroTomono さあ…^^ 僕もその形のは見たことないですし中身が知りたいです

Comment: @brocolli 隣はおにぎりなんでワッフルはかなりキツいですな…（笑）^^

Comment: @KentaroTomono ラーメン半炒飯が許されるならこれもアリなんじゃないですかｗ

Comment: @brocolli 超スイーツ派ですか。まあ確かに中身が解らないと何ともいえないのでDVは取り消そうとしたらすんんません。時間切れだそうです(m_m)。

Comment: @KentaroTomono `DVは取り消そうとしたら・・・時間切れだそうです` -> コメントのあとで回答が編集されていますので、もう取り消せますよ。

Comment: @KentaroTomono いあいあ、metaの質問に、ここのリンクが貼ってあったんで、たまたま開いたんです・・・

Answer (score 6):

I agree, looks like アメリカンドッグ made with the following:

[Corn dog maker with similar pattern on batter](https://goo.gl/images/aE5Gc7)

[image]

Comment: I think you have more chance to get the right answer as I am saying at Brocolli's comment, it is to "sweet" for people to eat waffle with Onigiri. You go to a fat man straightly in shor time. lol.

Comment: Isn't the picture David is showing the very thing OP is showing????? Am I biased? man...haha.